# how to handle the simplest dependent action in ant?

Tags: java, ant, dependencies

In a Makefile, I would simply specify

```
.a.b:
    do_something_with_a $< --output=$*.b
```

How do I do exactly that in ant? I haven't seen this in any documentation, and can't get it to work with ant.

For those who don't know make, the first part specifies two kind of files, those with .a extension and those with .b extension. Further it specifies that the bs are dependent on the as, such that if filename.b does not exist or is older than filename.a, the command rule should be applied. The command rule specifies that the command "do_something_with_a" is called with the arguments "filename.a" and "--output==filename.b" for every such filename.

I will test your solution with ant-1.8.4 and accept the first that works. File locations may be specified.

Comment: Ant has a _completely_ different philosophy about builds. It only tracks dependencies between targets but not files. File dependencies (like "*.java" to "*.class") are handled by the task-plugins. Better you adapt the new philosophy and write approriate plugins or you will, step by step, enter a long way of pain. (Been there, done that)

Comment: So, what would be a good documentation about writing ant-plugins for handling dependencies?

Comment: Page http://ant.apache.org/manual/. From there either "Developing with Ant" -> "Writing your own Task" AND/OR (root) -> Tutorial -> Writing Tasks. Also in "Developing with Ant" there is a quick skim through "Ant Task Guidelines" (where you find "Do your own Dependency Checking") and "Tasks designed for Extension" where I guess you will reuse `MatchingTask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This abstract dependency is not possible in ant.